Kubuntu installation stuck
I tried to install kubuntu I did all the steps necessary I flashed it on to a micro sd card then I changed the bios boot settings after that I clocked the try and install option but it getting stuck in the beginning it self ,it showing
The nothing else is happening please help
Sd 0:0:0:0:[sda] attached script removable disk

As written there is no info on what you have done so no way to help. You have failed to even say what the version you tried to install is.Please use edit and add some details.

Did you verify the ISO after download? do any validation of the ISO write to your media?  As you've not said which release you were using, we don't even know what installer you were using (ie. was it ubiquity?? or calamares??)  and like @David I don't know how far you got from your explanation.  Taking a picture & providing a link to a location where we could view it may help us to understand, as well as details (esp. release detail)

What brand/model system? What version of Kubuntu? Not all systems boot directly from sd cards. Normally they boot from USB flash drives. You may be able to  put sd card into a USB adapter and have that work as then it is seen as USB drive.

I fixed by installing the latest version
I had flashed kubuntu 22.04lts it didn't work then I removed that and flashed kubuntu 24.04 lts that worked for me
